# Who is it referring to in 舌先が動き、吸い上げられる度に呼吸が荒くなる

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm a bit confused in the below. The scene is describing two people kissing but I'm a bit confused on the last sentence, grammatically how does one understand 舌先が動き、吸い上げられる? From what I understand this is describing her doing these things, (her tongue is the one moving and she is doing the 'sucking'), but why is it not written with 吸い上げる like in the sentence before it?

> 彼女は何度も絡めた舌を動かし吸い上げ、唇を押し付けてディープキスを繰り返す。ねっとりした感触が口内いっぱいに広がって**、舌先が動き、吸い上げられる度に呼吸が荒くなる**。

Comment: I would think the second sentence (if not the first, too) is narrated from the perspective of the person being kissed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the act itself is a mutual act, there are cases where the act is performed by oneself and cases where it is performed by the other party, so I think this is the expression.

My translation:

> She sucked on his tongue and he sucked on hers again, which turned her on. She herself reacted passively to his actions.

The word "られる" has four meanings. 1. express spontaneity: I can feel a hint of autumn. 2. the possibility: the beautiful cherry blossoms that represent 3.Show respect: I wear the uniform on the day of the event. 4. expressing passivity: it was annoying to come in the middle of the night.

Quoted from Kojien, 6th ed.:

> 「られる」には４つの意味があります。 1.自発を表す　秋の気配を感じられる 2.可能を表す　美しい桜の花が見られる 3.尊敬を表す　当日は制服を着用せられたい 4.受け身を表す 夜中に来られて迷惑した 広辞苑 第六版から引用